# Google Maps API V3 : When showing direction zoom is ignored

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a map where I need to show the road from Point A to B. So far so good. I have got 2 issues: the 1st one is that the zoom level en center options are ignored and the marker showing Point B appears twice

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

And here is the code:

```
//set your google maps parameters
    var latitude = -36.33378,
        longitude = -72.25506,
        map_zoom = 11;

    //google map custom marker icon - .png fallback for IE11
    var is_internetExplorer11= navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('trident') > -1;


    //define the basic color of your map, plus a value for saturation and brightness
    var main_color = '#2d313f',
        saturation_value= -20,
        brightness_value= 5;

    //we define here the style of the map
    var style= [ 
        {
            //set saturation for the labels on the map
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                {saturation: saturation_value}
            ]
        },  
        {   //poi stands for point of interest - don't show these lables on the map 
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                {visibility: "off"}
            ]
        },
        {
            //don't show highways lables on the map
            featureType: 'road.highway',
            elementType: 'labels',
            stylers: [
                {visibility: "off"}
            ]
        }, 
        {   
            //don't show local road lables on the map
            featureType: "road.local", 
            elementType: "labels.icon", 
            stylers: [
                {visibility: "off"} 
            ] 
        },
        { 
            //don't show arterial road lables on the map
            featureType: "road.arterial", 
            elementType: "labels.icon", 
            stylers: [
                {visibility: "off"}
            ] 
        },
        {
            //don't show road lables on the map
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "geometry.stroke",
            stylers: [
                {visibility: "off"}
            ]
        }, 
        //style different elements on the map
        { 
            featureType: "transit", 
            elementType: "geometry.fill", 
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "poi.government",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "poi.sport_complex",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "poi.attraction",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "transit",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "transit.station",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "landscape",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]

        },
        {
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "road.highway",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            featureType: "water",
            elementType: "geometry",
            stylers: [
                { hue: main_color },
                { visibility: "on" }, 
                { lightness: brightness_value }, 
                { saturation: saturation_value }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.826934, -73.0501711),
        pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.83378, -72.75506)

    //set google map options
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: map_zoom,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        scrollwheel: true,
        styles: style,
    }
    //inizialize the map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), map_options);


    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "Concepción Centro",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "Lomas De Santa Rosa",
            label: "B",

            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: pointA,
            destination: pointB,
            avoidTolls: true,
            avoidHighways: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

See running script here http://jsfiddle.net/Corobori/v7e1m29g/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanations

1. *the zoom level en center options are ignored* because you are using direction service between two points.This will override the map center and zoom. In order to preserve this use [preserveViewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)
2. *marker showing Point B appears twice* this is again due to direction service(travelMode DRIVING) you are using.It will point to place which is most suitable. I think its better to remove **marker** for pointA and pointB and use marker provided by direction service

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/6vchx1cp/1/)

Extract from code

```
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true  //Added to preserve viewport
  }),
```